# Want to batch move all files from directories and sub directories in to a different folders

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a Windows directory and in it I have 4000 main sub-directories, in those main sub-directories I have 4000 sub-directories in which  I have around 20 files each with syntax `File_CreationDate_NUMBER_name.ext`.

Example:

> F:\DIR\MAINSUB1\SUB2\file_date_number*.rar
>
> F:\DIR\MAINSUB1\SUB3\file1_date_number*.img
>
> F:\DIR\MAINSUB1\SUB3\file2_date_*.txt
>   .... till 400 SUB directories then
>
> F:\DIR\MAINSUB2\SUB1\file2_date_number*.txt
>
> F:\DIR\MAINSUB2\SUB2\file2_date_number*.timg
>
> F:\DIR\MAINSUB2\SUB3\file2_date_*.html

There are 4000 MainSub directories and in each MainSub directory there are 10000 sub Directories.

I want a batch file which copies these files from SUB1, SUB2 ... under MAINSUB directories ...

Example:

> D:\FILES\MAINSUB1\all the files from its SUBS into it..
>
> D:\FILES\MAINSUB2\all the files from its SUBS into it..
>
> .... for all 4000 MAINSUB directories

I also want it to give me a prompt to add date in format DDMMYYYY and NUMBER from 0-4.

Comment: You want to rename the files before coppying them to the backup folder?  Also what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

This will handle the move of files (if used from command line, replace %% with %).

```
for /D %%f in ("d:\files\*") do for /D %%g in ("%%~ff\*") do move "%%~fg\*" "%%~ff"
```

Not sure where you want the timestamp added. Adjust as needed

EDIT - to adapt to comments

@echo off

```
setlocal enableextensions

rem from/where to copy
set "source=f:\dir"
set "target=d:\files"

set /p "df=date of files ? :"
set /p "nf=number ? :"

rem ensure final target directory exists
if not exist "%target%" mkdir "%target%"

rem do file copy
for /D %%f in ("f:\files\*") do (
    if not exist "%target%\%%~nxf" mkdir "%target%\%%~nxf" > nul
    for /D %%g in ("%%~ff\*") do (
        copy "%%~fg\*_%df%_%nf%*" "%target%\%%~nxf"
    )
)

endlocal
```

Comment: @foxidrive, as i read, the OP is just showing two examples. But here is too late. Will see tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. i want to copy the files and do not move them.. moreover is i guess it is copying the files mainsub directory wise.. is it possible to add a code that it will create mainsub folders in D:\ drive as it is in F:\ drive and then copy files from their respective subfolders into the mainsub directories created automatically in D:\ drive

Comment: No, this will not work. The first `for` is to match all the **folders** under `f:\files` (you MAINSUBx folders), and the second `for` will match all the **folders** under MAINSUBx (your SUBx folders) and then copy all the files inside to a corresponding MAINSUBx under %target% folder. You have two problems: you are trying to put a file mask in a `for` designed to handle folders, and `%date%` variable in mask will be expanded to current date, no to a match with a date in filenames.

Comment: please providfe me a complete solution as i am a little dull in it

Comment: You have a complete solution. Change `"f:\files\*"` in code to `"d:\program files\NCR\*"`

Comment: its not making the folders like
 target folder i.e. D:\FILES\MAINSUB1 and copying data. its creating file by the MAINSUB folder.

moreover i dont want the time stamp in folder i want that it should ask it to me while entering as files have date in their syntax and i want to copy files created on a specific date,
please help

Comment: As close as question as i can see. Adapt as needed